# Possible to create sparse Pandas DataFrame with string columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create a sparse Pandas DataFrame that has columns both containing floats and strings?
I.e, I have a dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0., 1., 2., 0.], 
                    'B': ['a','b','c','d']}, columns=['A','B'])
```

And I want to convert this to a sparse dataframe, but df2.to_sparse(fill_value=0.) gives:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: d
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is map your strings to ints/floats and map your column B to their dict lookup values into a new column C and then create the sparse dataframe like so:

```
temp={}
# we want just the unique values here for the dict
for x in enumerate(df2['B'].unique().tolist()):
    val, key = x
    temp[key]=val
temp

Out[106]:
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}

# now add this column

In [108]:

df2['C']=df2['B'].map(temp)
df2
Out[108]:
   A  B  C
0  0  a  0
1  1  b  1
2  2  c  2
3  0  d  3

# now pass the two columns to create the sparse matrix:

In [109]:

df2[['A', 'C',]].to_sparse(fill_value=0)
Out[109]:
   A  C
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  0  3
```